# Referring to a cell value in a list which is to be sorted

Tags: excel

I have a list of names in sheet1, A1:A5:

```
Fanny
Ann
Chris
Tony
Maria
```

In sheet2 I will show Tony, so I write the formula ='sheet1'!A4.

If I sort the list of names, another name is shown in sheet2. Can I avoid this and still show Tony?

Comment: there must be a bigger picture to this.  What is so special about that one cell in the list?  Is there another correlation that can be used to write a more dynamic formula?  Because as far as I know, no there is no way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign an index key to the value you wish to track.  For example:

[image]

Then in the other sheet, the formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A5,MATCH(4,Sheet1!B1:B5,0))
```

gets you *Tony*.

If you sort Sheet1, the same formula will still find *Tony.*

Comment: This is what I was trying to find out.  There had to be some sort of index column already in place that made this one cell important.